# Combining First Two Cases in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query part which has

```
$PendingNewquery = "
        CASE
            WHEN s.pending='Y' THEN 'P'
            WHEN MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'N' 
            WHEN s.Pending='Y' OR MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'PN'
        END
```

I am not getting any results for 'PN' which combines first two cases. How can I do that without using `WHERE`?

Comment: What is the second `THEN 'P'` for?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results when S.pending= Y and when it's not Y and when max(fqc.changetime) is null and not null?  is it possible fqc.change time is always null so 'N' will always be set and PN would never get hit?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your case statement like:

```
CASE
    WHEN s.Pending='Y' AND MAX(ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'PN' 
    WHEN s.pending='Y' THEN 'P'
    WHEN MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'N'  
END
```

I believe using an "AND" and moving your last line to top would make more sense in your situation, since you would see PN or NULL in your main query if you use with "OR" as a result. However if you insist using OR, then:

```
CASE
    WHEN s.pending='Y' THEN 'P'
    WHEN MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'N' 
    WHEN s.Pending='Y' OR MAX(ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'PN' 
END
```

Comment: Balkani. I modified the query and it too doesn't work. It is working sequentially and breaking when a match is found. I just want 'PN' as a result combined with both P and N.

Comment: Which one you tried, bottom? If so, yes, you will see either PN or NULL in the output.Try the top one if you don't want this way

Comment: The top one seems right to me... when both conditions are met then PN, otherwise set the appropriate value for which condition is true.  and if no conditions are true then return null.

Comment: So I tried `WHEN s.Pending='Y' OR MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'PN' 
    WHEN s.pending='Y' THEN 'P'
    WHEN MAX(fqc.ChangeTime) IS NULL THEN 'N'  `

Comment: @sruthy123 change OR keyword into AND please